# user entered value to variable to text

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do, when the user enters a value that matches one of the two variables I want the entered value then to 'trigger' the variable. So basically, you enter the name of the variable in a prompt then I want a paragraph tag to get the text that the variable holds.

However I can't get it to work, since the entered value becomes the text and does not trigger the variable at all. It just converts into plain text.

I hope the snippet I provided clears up the rest of what I'm trying to achieve!

```js
var help = 'Put me in the paragraph tag please!'
  var no = 'Or me, either way it\'s fine!'


  $('.reset').on('click', function() {
    $('p').text('');
  });

  $('.go').on('click', function() {
 var key = prompt('Enter something bro').toLowerCase();
    
    $('p').text(key);


  });
```

```css
button {
  transition:color .3s;
  border:none;
  font-size:18px;
  color:white;
  padding:1%;
  width:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button:hover {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)
}

.go {
  background-color:#4CAF50;
}

.reset {
  background-color:#f44336;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>

<button class="go">Go</button>

<p>Replace me</p>
```

Comment: Probably `window[key](arguments)`? Javascript also has `eval()`, but noone actually recommends it because of security reasons. If you have, for example, `function one(text) { alert(text); }` at the root of your script, this should work as expected: `var funcName = "one"; window[funcName]("hello");`

Answer (score 2):

```js
  var decision={
    help : 'Put me in the paragraph tag please!',
    no : 'Or me, either way it\'s fine!'
  }


  $('.reset').on('click', function() {
    $('p').text('');
  });

  $('.go').on('click', function() {
 var key = prompt('Enter something bro').toLowerCase();
    
    $('p').text(decision[key]);


  });
```

```css
button {
  transition:color .3s;
  border:none;
  font-size:18px;
  color:white;
  padding:1%;
  width:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button:hover {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)
}

.go {
  background-color:#4CAF50;
}

.reset {
  background-color:#f44336;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>

<button class="go">Go</button>

<p>Replace me</p>
```

Here is a simple solution for your problem. Store your options not as variables but as an object. The  you can get the value of the option using the objects key. Or Directly getting the property of the object. For Details refer [Objects and Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

use the window global to output the value

```js
var help = 'Put me in the paragraph tag please!'
  var no = 'Or me, either way it\'s fine!'


  $('.reset').on('click', function() {
    $('p').text('');
  });

  $('.go').on('click', function() {
 var key = prompt('Enter something bro').toLowerCase();
    
    $('p').text(window[key]);


  });
```

```css
button {
  transition:color .3s;
  border:none;
  font-size:18px;
  color:white;
  padding:1%;
  width:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button:hover {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)
}

.go {
  background-color:#4CAF50;
}

.reset {
  background-color:#f44336;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>

<button class="go">Go</button>

<p>Replace me</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window[key]`

```js
    var help = 'Put me in the paragraph tag please!'
      var no = 'Or me, either way it\'s fine!'


      $('.reset').on('click', function() {
        $('p').text('');
      });

      $('.go').on('click', function() {
     var key = prompt('Enter something bro').toLowerCase();
    if(window[key] != undefined )
                alert(window[key]);
            $('p').text(window[key]);
      });
```

```css
    button {
      transition:color .3s;
      border:none;
      font-size:18px;
      color:white;
      padding:1%;
      width:100px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }

    button:hover {
      color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)
    }

    .go {
      background-color:#4CAF50;
    }

    .reset {
      background-color:#f44336;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>

    <button class="go">Go</button>

    <p>Replace me</p>
```

Comment: you realize that the answer is a duplicate of my answer?

Comment: I realized after i had clicked post answer

Comment: I do not know if he needs this, my code shows the text typed in addition to showing only variable text :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var help = 'Put me in the paragraph tag please!'
  var no = 'Or me, either way it\'s fine!'

  $('.reset').on('click', function() {
  
    $('p').text('');
  });

  $('.go').on('click', function() {
 var key = prompt('Enter something bro').toLowerCase();
   
    $('p').text(key);

  });
});
  </script>
```

you must use document.ready function to execute jquery code..

Comment: whatever code you have written is 100% correct just use $(document).ready(function(){}); in your code as i did in the answer.

Comment: Although this addresses part of the problem, which is attaching events to the DOM after it is ready, it doesn't solve the OP's question, which is referencing a function with it's name in a string and run it,

Answer (score 0):

Use `window[key]` to use enter text into compare with variable

```js
var help = 'Put me in the paragraph tag please!'
  var no = 'Or me, either way it\'s fine!'


  $('.reset').on('click', function() {
    $('p').text('');
  });

  $('.go').on('click', function() {
 var key = prompt('Enter something bro').toLowerCase();
    var name = window[key];
    $('p').text(name);


  });
```

```css
button {
  transition:color .3s;
  border:none;
  font-size:18px;
  color:white;
  padding:1%;
  width:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button:hover {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)
}

.go {
  background-color:#4CAF50;
}

.reset {
  background-color:#f44336;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>

<button class="go">Go</button>

<p>Replace me</p>
```